# Writing multiple-line description in Xcode for parameters in Objective-C documentation

Tags: xcode, objective-c

I am trying to do this:

```
/**
 @param argumentString This is a multiline
 comment
 about
 argumentString
 */
- (void)doSomething:(NSString *)argumentString;
```

But I don't think `@param` supports multiple lines describing the same parameter. I haven't been able to find out a way to do this yet; my end goal is to make all the text appear in the same section in the correct segment. With the above code the `comment about argumentString` part will be moved to the Description section instead. I've tried using [`@parblock`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparblock) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very [easy to do](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH54-SW1) in Swift, but for Objective-C, there's a simple hack which can make a parameter description look like it is in multiple lines.

Simply add another param whose first word is a [whitespace unicode character](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html) (other than space). In the following example, I have copied the unicode U+2007 in the 2nd line.

```
/**
 This is the description

 @param argumentString: This is a comment,
 @param   which looks like a multiline comment
*/
- (void)doSomething:(NSString *)argumentString;
```

The second @param line in the example above is effectively this:

```
@param U+2007 <space> <comment-text>
```

The unicode which you could copy is :

**Result**

This is how it renders in Xcode:

[image: objective-c xcode multi line comment description example]

[image: objective-c xcode multi line comment description example 2]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/**
* @param argumentString This is a multiline
*                       comment
*                       about
*                       argumentString
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works, and it fits the bounty description, but I forgot to add that the generated description in Quick Help should also have corresponding linebreaks where line breaks are present in the comment. Is there a way to achieve that too?

Comment: as far as I understand, no, there is not